# Why does SO keep obviously wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

Like here [Django: How to check if the user left all fields blank (or to initial values)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572859/django-how-to-check-if-the-user-left-all-fields-blank-or-to-initial-values) where the only correct answer is provided by the OP.

Comment: SO can't detect if an answer is wrong. Only the community can. You are part of the community. If you find it wrong, downvote it and leave a comment.

Comment: Actually, "use an undocumented function" hardly sounds like a "correct" answer -- sounds like an ugly hack. But then I'm not one of the few, the proud, the Django sufferers.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill At least it achieves the result OP is asking for, in contratry to the rest of the answers.

Answer (score 10):

If an answer is wrong, you can do three things:

1. downvote it
2. comment it
3. give a better answer.

If you blame SO for wrong answers, remember that SO is a communtity, and you are part of it. So better try to correct a wrong immediately.

Besides if somebody asks: what is 2+2, and 5 is given as an answer, it can get lots of upvotes, but it's still wrong.

Comment: I have better things to do than play your reputation game (which is not simple to enter as it has progressed this much), so I cant downvote (or even upvote atm) the wrong answers. Usualy I often do not have an answer or answer already is there burried somewhere. But I still can identify answers that dont solve the question asked.

Comment: Yes it takes time and effort to be part of the community. And I assumed that because you raised this issue, you have some interest in making this site better.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers don't have a negative score, so perhaps they're not "obviously wrong".  Besides, answers can be upvoted for being *helpful* or whatever else without being perfect.

If you think they're bad and not useful, downvote them or and/or leave a clarifying comment.  Most posts with huge negative scores get removed by their authors.

Moderators may not be experts on every specific subject on the site, so they don't delete posts based on whether something is wrong or right.  Voting is supposed to fill that gap.

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between *wrong* answers and answers that *aren't what you're looking for*. I haven't seen many (any?) flat out wrong answers. If you do see an answer with inaccurate information, comment so and consider down voting.

Comment: True. I have seen cases of plain wrong answers being eventually deleted by a moderator or two 20K members.

Comment: Those answers do not solve the issue OP is asking. Therefore they are wrong, it's that simple.

Comment: @user1362977 If the answer really doesn't answer the question, flag it as "not an answer"

Comment: @user1362977 what I'd like to know is how you figure yourself an authority on SO having many wrong answers. I sure would be impressed to meet a person who's an expert on every subject SO covers. I mean really, how many *wrong* answers have you seen?

Comment: @simchona How can you flag it as "not an answer" ?

Comment: @Celeritas stop doing assumptions and making stuff up, please.

Comment: @user Under a given answer, there should be a few links--"link", "edit" and "flag"